# uiwebview SoundCloud embed frame won't play unless you click play twice

Tags: xcode, uiwebview, soundcloud

I have a webview that its loading a SoundCloud embedded frame to load an HTML 5 audio player. Everything works great except I have to click the play button twice before it plays. I'm not sure if this is something to do with SoundCloud or just a setting I have to change in the webview/code itself.

Thanks.

- Rico.

Embed Code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="133" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F{trackID}&color=ff6600&auto_play=false&show_artwork=false&amp;sharing=false"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figure out the problem. The widget has a mouse over so the first time you tap on it, it registers the mouse over, the second is the actual play. I ended up using a hidden uibutton over the widget and using JS to control the play and stop.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not loading it on first go, If its loaded, then it should take one press. Can you post the link from where integrated the widget. i will guide you then.

Comment: I actually figure out the problem. The widget has a mouse over so the first time you tap on it, it registers the mouse over, the second is the actual play. I ended up using a hidden uibutton over the widget and using JS to control the play and stop.

Comment: nice way of tackling this

Comment: Please share embed frame code that you have used for soundcloud... thanks

Comment: I edited my question to include the embed code. You can get this code from the "share" section of any audio file in Soundcloud. I changed the options using a script to make it easier for our client when they copy and paste. the "sharing=false" I added to disable sharing. It's not one of the options SoundCloud provides but you can added to hide the share button.